# Writing a script that copy files to sub folder

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

I need your help in writing a script(ubuntu-bash). suppose i have a folder in a certain name and i want to copy all the files in the folder to a sub-folder that starts with the first letter of the file. for instance, a file named `alaska` will be copied to folder "A", the file named `colorado` will be cppied to folder "C" and so on. of course it will include files with lowercase and uppercase letters and a folder with one uppercase letter.

thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Please review the FAQ. We try to answer specific programming questions and this is a bit too broad and doesn't contain enough information to give a specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you can build on this example:

```
for f in file1 file2; do
    dir=$(echo ${f:0:1} | tr a-z A-Z)
    mkdir -p $dir
    cp -v "$f" $dir
done
```